# odd spacing between elements

Tags: css, margin, padding

I have a landing page with three sections- a most recent blog section, an about section, and a Tweeter feed.
These elements are all styled the same and in the same format, however something is not quite right with the most recent blog section.
Specifically, there is a larger space under, `<h2><a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/blog">Growing Edge Blog</a></h2>`, and `<a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/home"><span style="color:#b8bf33">Continue Reading</span></a></p>` is much further down and larger than it should be.

Any ideas?

[Live site.](http://growingedgecoaching.com/)

This is the relevant code:

```
<div id="landing-brief">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/blog">Growing Edge Blog</a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php
                    // Get the most recent post
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1' );

                    // Pull the excerpt
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                        the_excerpt();
                    endwhile;

                    // Reset Post Data
                    wp_reset_postdata(); 
                    ?>
                <br /><br /><a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/home"><span style="color:#b8bf33">Continue Reading</span></a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="index.php?page_id=27">Meet Mary Anne</a></h2>
                <p>Mary Anne is the founder of Growing Edge Coaching™, a coaching and consulting company, where she helps individuals and companies develop powerful strategies to move forward in their life, their work, or their business. Her coaching is founded on her 20 years of experience as a manager and senior leader in non-profits. <br /><br /><a href="index.php?page_id=27"><span style="color:#b8bf33">More About Mary Anne</span></a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="#">Recent Tweets</a></h2>
                <div id="twitter-feed">
                    <?php
                        include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
                        $rss = fetch_feed('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=Growing_Edge');
                        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
                        $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
                        ?>

                        <ul>
                        <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
                        else
                        // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
                        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
                        <li>
                        <?php echo str_replace('Growing_Edge: ', '', $item->get_title()); ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- end twitter-feed -->
                <br /><br /><a href="https://twitter.com/growing_edge"><p><span style="color:#b8bf33">Follow @Growing_Edge</span></p></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end brief -->


#landing-brief {
    width: 860px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#landing-brief ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 250px;
}

#landing-brief ul li:last-child {
    padding-right: none;
}

#landing-brief ul li p span {
    color: #b8bf33;
}

#landing-brief #twitter-feed {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #333333;
    margin-left: -28px;
}

#landing-brief #twitter-feed ul li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h2><a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/blog">Growing Edge Blog</a></h2>
<p>
 <p>“Embrace the messy imperfect genius. Seek to be misunderstood by creative minds.” ~Ross Martin One thing I have learned over the years as an entrepreneur is that when I am in my most creative space, I have to release being a perfectionist and jump into my creative messiness. I need to create space that allows [...]</p>
 <br /><br />
 <a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/home"><span style="color:#b8bf33">Continue Reading</span></a>
</p>
```

should be this:

```
<h2><a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/blog">Growing Edge Blog</a></h2>
<p>
  “Embrace the messy imperfect genius. Seek to be misunderstood by creative minds.” ~Ross Martin One thing I have learned over the years as an entrepreneur is that when I am in my most creative space, I have to release being a perfectionist and jump into my creative messiness. I need to create space that allows [...]
 <br /><br />
 <a href="http://growingedgecoaching.com/home"><span style="color:#b8bf33">Continue Reading</span></a>
</p>
```

I suggest you to use inspect tools like Chrome Developer toolbar to inspect the page, it gives lots of information, help you figure out where's the problem.

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot that Wordpress likes to add extra `<p>`s.
That doesn't account for the odd space between the excerpt and the "Continue Reading" link though- any ideas on that?

Comment: Now it's `<p>Embrace the...</p><br/><br/><p><a href=...>...</a></p>`, that's not correct too. It should be `<p>Emb...<br/><br/><a href...>...</a></p>`. Look at your other two sections, both with this hierarchy.

Comment: Oh wait, do you want the *continue Reading* link and *More About Mary Anne* in the same baseline?

Comment: If I could get all three of the green links on the same line, that would be great.

Comment: Otherwise, just equal spacing between the elements will do.

Comment: How do you populate these content, with CMS like WordPress? As I looked into your HTML source, I think removing the extra `<br/>` should work.